# Using 'this' before calling a method.

Tags: java, methods

So I have a simple programming question that I can't seem to find the answer for. While browsing some code from Google I noticed that they put 'this' in front of a lot of methods in their code. What is the purpose of doing this? Does it have any benefits over not using it?

An example:

```
this.doMethod();
```

Compared to:

```
doMethod();
```

I'm sure its a simple answer, I just like being able to understand all of the code that I read.

Comment: This is rather a question about Java and OOP, but not Android-specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it makes no difference at all for method calls. Use whichever you find more readable.

Note that it *does* make a difference when disambiguating between instance variables and parameters (or other local variables though). For example:

```
public void setFoo(int foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}
```

That's assigning the *instance variable* a value from the parameter - just using `foo = foo;` would be a no-op.

Comment: I thought it might have to do with constructors thanks everyone for clearing this up for me!

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between them at all. You always call a method on some reference. If you don't use any reference, `this` reference is implicit.

So, `doMethod()` is same as `this.doMethod()`. By using `this`, you just make it explicit.

One place where it is required to use `this` reference explicitly is the place where you are assigning the value of method/constructor parameter to the instance variable, and both have same name, as in the below example:

```
public Demo(int var) {  // Constructor
    this.var = var;
}
```

So, in the above example, `this.var` refers to instance variable and is different from `var`, which refers to constructor parameter.

Answer (score 3):

`this` represents the object instance of the current class. **In programming practice, most of the time, it is used to break the ambiguity.** e.g. in example, there is a class variable named `name` and method parameter named `named`, so this is used to differentiate the two.

```
     public void setName(String name){
         this.name= name;
     }
```

If you don't have any ambiguity then it doesn't create much difference i.e. `setName("John");` and `this.setName("John");` is same thing. But still there is one difference. **`this.setName("John");` follows the same pattern as you are calling the method on objects(e.g. `emp.setName("A");`);** here `this` representing the sane class object.